# Where does system.out.println print from a JSP?

Tags: jsp, logging, println

Where does tomcat put the `System.out.println` output ?

I'm not interested in `out.println`. I'm using a system that uses `system.out` to log issues, like login success/fail, and I need to look to that generated "log".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It usually prints to catalina.out.

It is highly unrecommended to log using system.out.println() from several reasons:

- you cannot control which messages are logged and which aren't unless you change the code
- catalina.out just grow all the time, and you cannot move it so that tomcat will create another one.

A better solution is to use one of the popular (and mature) logging frameworks:

- [java.util.logging](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) (actually used by tomcat itself and you have no third party dependencies)
- [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/index.html)
- [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/)

A good solution which is backed by log4j, is to use Jakarta's log tag library, where you can have your logging messages in any of this forms

```
<log:info message="this is a message"/>

<log:info category="foo.bar" message="this is a message"/>

<log:info category="foo.bar">
  this is a message
</log:info>
```

Comment: The author of Log4J left the project and is working on logback (for some time already) which works in combination of slf4j. Both should be the preferred logging frameworks.

Comment: @Brice I agree, SLF4J is my preference these days as well. It also has  a JSP tag library, documented at http://www.slf4j.org/taglib/

Answer (score 3):

*CATALINA_HOME*/logs/stdout_YYYYMMDD.log

is the default, where *CATALINA_HOME* is your base Tomcat directory. There are various ways to change this programatically and via configuration.

Comment: $ ls /usr/local/tomcat/logs
admin.2009-10-06.log  catalina.2009-10-06.log  catalina.out  host-manager.2009-10-06.log  localhost.2009-10-06.log  manager.2009-10-06.log  tomcat.log

in none of this files i notice any change with a system.out.println, where should this configuration be ?
tnx!

Comment: What version of Tomcat are you running?