# In Tomcat, how can I output message to console by using System.out.println

Tags: tomcat

In my java code, I have System.out.println(...) statement which is invoked by jsp. But I don't see anything being written to tomcat console. I've googled around and seems no clear answer on it.

I'm using tomcat 6.0.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543997/jsp-where-system-out-println-prints

Answer (score 3):

Usually (on default setup) the messages of the `System.out.println(...)` statement can be found in your `./apache-tomcat6.0/logs/catalina.out` logfile.

Comment: there are some logs under logs directory, one of them is catalina.[date].log. But it doesn't have the output messages.

Comment: the catalina.[date].log is a logfile that is turned over. if there are catalina.[date].logs, there must also be the catalina.out log somewhere. try: "find / -name catalina.out"

Comment: under installation home. I did "find . -iname catalina.out", didn't return anything. Not sure what's wrong.

Comment: what logfiles beneath catalina.[date].log are there? Is there a catalina.[date].log file with a date from yesterday? Which is the newest date?

Comment: there are files like catalina.2010-07-08.log, host-manager.2010-07-08.log and manager.2010-07-08.log

Comment: ok - then there must be a catalina-logfile too, since these files are the archived files from your logfile-rotation of the day before. I'm sorry, that I can't search the file for you on your system. Here you will find help about tomcat-logging: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/logging.html

Answer (score 2):

Verify `apache/tomcat/logs/stdout.log` file.