# Where does the print line go when executing JSP files?

Tags: jsp

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<%
    // This is a scriptlet.  Notice that the "date"
    // variable we declare here is available in the
    // embedded expression later on.
    System.out.println( "Evaluating date now" );
    java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
%>
Hello!  The time is now <%= date %>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

This is a simple JSP file. I put it under Tomcat's webapp directory and access it via http://localhost:8080.

It works fine except I have no idea where the output of println goes. In other words, how can I observe the output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSP: where system.out.println prints?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543997/jsp-where-system-out-println-prints)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This prints to console so either the where tomcat is running (it its in foreground) or the file where that is redirected.

"- I have Tomcat 5.5 and it is under the /log folder the logfile catalina.log "

http://www.coderanch.com/t/468689/Tomcat/redirect-Tomcat-console-output-log