# How to get System.out.println in servlet to show on console?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, console

I am running a simple servlet on Tomcat 7.0 in Windows.

For the sake of debugging I want to

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // do some stuff
    System.out.println("Some stuff was done");
    ...

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("Done");
}
```

However, I do not see my System.out.println output in either the console or any of the log files in the logs folder, be it catalina.log or catalina.out. I have searched this many times, but none of the methods I read work.

All I need is for my output to show up on the console without having to use other utilities, so I'd really appreciate it if someone can show me the steps on how to fix it.

Comment: Have you checked TOMCAT/logs/catalina.<date>.log?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543997/where-does-system-out-println-print-from-a-jsp.

Comment: Check for some logging framework configuration file, such as `log4j.xml`, they may be redirecting your standard output. Also, try `System.err.println("...");`, it may help.

Comment: Tomcat outs all `System.out.print` to catalina.out file in logs directory.

Comment: To everyone who replied: I have already checked *all* the log files, including catalina.out. I keep getting this answer on every search result I get, but my output's not there.

Comment: Try a logger instead, like slf4j to see if you're getting output from there. Even if you want to use println, at least this will tell you if it's an issue with println or you have a deeper problem. It's also possible that something is changing your System.out.

Comment: Write a simple hello world program with a main method and print something using System.out.println(). Run the program and check you can print to stdout. If it works the problem is in your set up. Since we don't know if this is a clean install that no-one's been playing with, it is difficult to trouble shoot. Either System.out has been configured to send it's output elsewhere, or it's being sent to a log file. Start with hello world, then progress to a clean install until you find the difference.

Comment: Do you call doPost method successfully? And how do you start tomcat?

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of debugging, use some log framework like [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/).

However, system.out logs will be in catalina.out or one of the localhost*.log files in your Tomcat's logs directory

Is there a specific reason you're not using a logging framework or the standard Java logging? It's quite a bit more useful, and configurable.