# java Scheduler is not working

Tags: java, tomcat, scheduler

I am using the following code as scheduler in java web deployment

```
public class ReportScheduler implements ServletContextListener {

    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ReportLoader(sce.getServletContext()), 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        scheduler.shutdownNow();
    }
```

The ReportLoader class which implements runnable is as follows:

```
public class ReportLoader implements Runnable {

    ServletContext context;

    public ReportLoader(ServletContext context) {
        System.out.println("1");
        this.context = context;
        StartUp();
    }
     private void StartUp() {
    System.out.println("start");
    (new Thread(this)).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("scheduled");
        try {
            //Files.delete(path);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

But my Scheduler does not seem to be working as nothing is getting printed on the tomcat (which is my server) log, as one would expect to.

Is there any mistake that i am making, or something more that i need to ensure so that the scheduler works properly ?

The intention of the scheduler is to delete folders at regular intervals on the local PC.

Comment: Have you registered the listener,in the web.xml or using annotations? Why do you start a thread from the constructor of your runnable?

Comment: i was just trying out the thread part. should have removed it. my mistake. and could you elaborate on what you mean by "registered" to web.xml ?

Comment: Are you looking [in the right logs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1548974/1079354)?  I wouldn't recommend using `System.out` anyway; use a proper logging service.

Comment: Just because you have a class implementing ServletContextListener in your application doesn't mean Tomcat will find it and call it. Just like servlets, filters, etc. listeners must be declared in the web.xml (or using annotations since servlet 3.0). Use google to find out how.

Answer (score -1):

why use threadpool to run a Thread
your code：

```
private void StartUp() {
    System.out.println("start");
    (new Thread(this)).start();
 }
```