# System.out.println() in JSP page not displaying anything

Tags: jsp

I am working on a project in JSP in Netbeans. I want to show something in my console. But unfortunately System.out.println() is not showing anything in the console. The program runs fine. Is there anything I have to change in the Netbeans setting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does system.out.println print from a JSP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543997/where-does-system-out-println-print-from-a-jsp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out catalina.log in your Tomcat/logs folder - all System.out data may be there if this feature was enabled